# Using velocity macro for a string.format function can`t seem to recognise the parameter

Tags: c#, velocity

I`m trying to make a macro for Velocity that do a String.format function. I cannot figure out if my syntax is bad or where the problem comes from. If i change the parameter to an random int value it works. otherwise is not working

```
    #macro (prinHexU8 $abc) //declaration
    $test.localStringFormat ("{0:X2}", $abc) #end //macro
    #prinHexU8($function()) // use of macro
```

The function works fine, it prints in the template what i want, but velocity is not recognising the test.localStringFormat(...) thing with this parameter. Is there any way to declare the parameter as an int or something like this?
EDIT: output is this:  $test.localStringFormat ("{0:X2}", $function())

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: It's a c# nuget - nvelocity. It uses some of the c# syntax inside the templates